# Projectile motion of a grenade

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, projectile

> A small hand grenade is thrown with an initial speed V0 forming an
>   angle ɵ with the horizontal ground.
>
> Assume that at its highest point the grenade explodes and is split
>   into two identical parts. Knowing that one of the parts travels down
>   along the same path followed by the grenade from launching to
>   explosion, determine the distance between the landing points of both
>   parts.

The easiest option seems to be that they receive an equal but opposite force from the explosion and the second object simply traces out the same path in the opposite direction.

However, just before the explosion occurs the grenade has a horizontal velocity component Vx. If it had simply split into two parts rather than explode, both parts would retain this velocity Vx, both of magnitude Vx and both in the same direction. Does this need to be accounted for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this in a couple of different ways.
1) The motion of the center of mass of the particles will follow the same path the grenade would have followed if it had not exploded.
2) The total momentum of the two pieces *immediately after* the explosion will be equal to the momentum of the grenade *immediately before* the explosion.

Enjoy the algebra and watch out for your - signs.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part to travel down the path of the full grenade, it must have a velocity $-V_x$. By taking momentum into account, it can then be shown that the other part must have a horizontal velocity $3V_x$. Momentum is conserved, even though kinetic energy is not. You can then use these new velocities to calculate the distance between the two points where the two pieces will land.

Comment: $(-V_x)\frac{m}{2}+2V_x\frac{m}{2}=V_x\frac{m}{2}$ ... this isn't equal to the original $V_x m$.  Try again!

Comment: @BillN Thanks for pointing that out; answer amended!

Comment: $\frac{3}{2}V_x$  is still not correct.

Comment: @BillN It's been one of those days... Answer (hopefully) corrected!